# Handle IPN on Cloud Functions of Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

On my client, I have an order which has the items I want to buy. When I "checkout" the order, I send a request to my firebase cloud function and the function responds with a link to the online payment transaction. After the customer completes the transaction, a request from the company (who serves the online payment service) is being dispatched to one of my cloud functions who shall process the payment.

After I validate the payment, I want to store the new data of my payment to the order (e.g. status, completion date etc...).

How can I store my new data? I know that with firestore I can simply use the `.set(..)` method.

Comment: Is there a problem in updating document stored in firestore? For more details you need то refer to the documentation [like this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data). Or there is a problem with identifying which document you should update? In this case you need to send document id to the transaction service. When postback will back from transaction service you will update required document in firestore using saved doc id

Comment: @OleksiiMiroshnyk can I use firestore on cloud functions? (rookie here)

Comment: Yes, you can. If you need to perform some operations with firestore inside your cloud functions just use `admin.firestore()` to get access to you database. Also you can handle different events on your documents. For more read [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions). And very simple example [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/uppercase-firestore)

Comment: That was what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @OleksiiMiroshnyk, could you please post your comments as an answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "After the customer completes the transaction, a request from the company (who serves the online payment service) is being dispatched to one of my cloud functions who shall process the payment." How did you dispatch the IPN to the Google Cloud function directly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634222/how-to-dispatch-a-paypal-ipn-to-a-google-cloud-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got my answer from the comments (Thanks to Oleskii Miroshnyk). Since Oleskii didn't post it as an Answer, then I will.

First, we need to import `firebase-admin`:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
```

or in Javascript:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
```

After that, we need to initialize our application like so:

```
const serviceAccount = require('../service-account-key.json');

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: 'https://{PROJECT-ID}.firebaseio.com'
});
```

The `service-account-key.json` can be found in your firebase settings.

Once I finish with the configuration, I have access to the `firestore` method like so:

```
const firestore = admin.firestore();

firestore.collection(...).doc(...).set(...)
```

That's it. Quite simple actually.

Comment: If you are using this in Cloud Functions for Firebase, you don't need to add credentials.  It happens automatically. `admin.initializeApp();`